# How long does it take to check in at Pudong Airport, Shanghai?

Tags: air-travel, airports, china, pvg

I need to fly from Pudong Airport (Shanghai) to the USA.  I have 1 checked bag.  How long do I need to allow for check-in, baggage drop-off, security, and customs exit?

Hainan Airline, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hainan Airlines' cut-off time](https://www.hainanairlines.com/HUPortal/dyn/portal/DisplayPage?COUNTRY_SITE=INT&SITE=CBHZCBHZ&LANGUAGE=GB&PAGE=ACIG) at PVG is one hour before departure, meaning you have to be checked in by this time.

Given that flights to the US involve some extra security hassle and that immigration times in China can be unpredictable (although departures are usually straightforward and there's no Customs on departure), I would recommend getting there **two hours** before.

Comment: FYI, test of this answer proved it to be 100% correct.  We arrived at the airport about 2.5 hours early, and had only only about 1/2 hour of idle time post-arrival.